# RecyclerView Fatal Exception:main

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Can some one assist me to know what has been causing this error in My recyclerview i have tried changing the variable name at

```
Adapter1.java:48
```

But it still giving me the same error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ke.co.clickaway.squirrel.clickawaytechnologies.adpter.Adapter1.getItemCount(Adapter1.java:48)
```

the code is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ArrayList<DataList> list;
//in the onCreate Bundle
RecyclerView rview=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rview);
        Adapter1 adapter1=new Adapter1(this,list);
        rview.setAdapter(adapter1);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager lm=new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rview.setLayoutManager(lm);
```

the information class

```
public class DataList {
    public int imageView;
    public String title;

    public static List<DataList> getData(){
        ArrayList<DataList> mList=new ArrayList<>();
        int[] imag={R.drawable.web_ic,R.drawable.palette_ic,R.drawable.pencil,R.drawable.sware_ic,R.drawable.phone_ic};
        String[] lable={"Web Development","Branding","Graphic Design","Systems","Mobile Apps"};
        for(int i=0;i<lable.length&& i<imag.length;i++){
            DataList dataList=new DataList();
            dataList.title=lable[i];
            dataList.imageView=imag[i];
            mList.add(dataList);
        }
        return mList;
    }
}
```

And My adapter

```
public class Adapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter1.ViewHolder> {
    private List<DataList> mList;
    private Context mContext;
    public Adapter1(Context context,List<DataList> list){
          mList=list;
          mContext=context;
    }
    private Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
    @Override
    public Adapter1.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context=parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View customView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(customView);
        return viewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter1.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         DataList dataList=mList.get(position);
         holder.imag.setImageResource(dataList.imageView);
         holder.lable.setText(dataList.title);
         }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imag;
        public TextView lable;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imag= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            lable=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        }
    }
}
```

my custom View

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/one" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="dummy Text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the RecyclerView snippet in activty_main.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/appbarlayout"
        android:id="@+id/rview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add this code :

```
list = Datalist.getData();
```

before this :

```
Adapter1 adapter1=new Adapter1(this,list);
```

Comment: wouldnt i have to have a getter method for the data from my DataList

Comment: Hey thanks alot it worked after i combined your answer with @casabapap's answer....

Answer (score 2):

**list** is null. So initialize your list before you create your adapter or change getItemCount() method in your adapter to this:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList == null ? 0 : mList.size();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot after i combined your answer with  Al zills answer it ran so smoothly Thanks alot...

Comment: in the getData() method, there is an initialization so it will never return null, the worse is empty list.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code the **list** is null, so instead of using `ArrayList<DataList> list` in **MainActivity**  use `ArrayList<DataList> list = new ArrayList<>()` or `ArrayList<DataList> list = DataList.getData()`